# WPF style present different while apply for multiply control

Tags: wpf, styles

I have two button with the code in xaml is:

```
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource styleInfomationButton}" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource styleInfomationButton}" />
```

They're same style, but in runtime they were presented differently:

Here the image how the form showed:

[image]

Style applied:

```
    <Style x:Key="styleInfomationButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="22" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="White">?</TextBlock>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid Width="20" Height="20">
                        <Ellipse Fill="#81A9F0" />
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried the above code, it failed at runtime with the error:

> > Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first

Then, I looked at the code again and see you are setting `Content` property in the style. When you tried to apply the `Style` to two buttons, WPF tries to set the *same* TextBlock element as `Content` for the two buttons - this can't work. In WPF, for any element, you can only have one logical parent.

Update your style to the following, to get the desired behavior:

```
<Style x:Key="styleInfomationButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid Width="20" Height="20">
                    <Ellipse Fill="#81A9F0" />
                    <<TextBlock FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">?</TextBlock> 
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Very good article on [Understanding the Visual Tree and Logical Tree in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21495/Understanding-the-Visual-Tree-and-Logical-Tree-in)

Comment: thanks you @sthotakura, for the infomation, the link about it and the way you resolved my problem.